# Как построчно читать textBox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Приложение открывает файл, и записывает его содержимое в `textBox1`
Код записи:

```
using (OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
{
     dialog.Filter = "Текстовые файлы|*.txt";
     if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
          textBox1.Text = "";
          textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(dialog.FileName);
     }
}
```

И по нажатию кнопки, мне нужно что бы `textBox1` начал построчно читаться и записываться в переменную, после чего с переменной проводится какое-то действие, и читается следующая строка.
Как реализовать подобное?

Comment: Winforms? Зачем построчно записываете в текстбокс и как именно вы это делаете? Покажите код.

Comment: просто содержимое файла переписывается в текст бокс

Comment: [StringReader](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stringreader?view=net-6.0) ?

Comment: исправил тему))

Comment: winforms это или что? Чем именно вас `File.WriteAllText("file.txt", textBox1.Text);` не устраивает?

Comment: код записи

using (OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                dialog.Filter = "Текстовые файлы|*.txt";
                if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = "";
                    textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(dialog.FileName);
                }
            }

Приложение виндовс форм

Comment: При чем тут код записи и OpenFileDialog? Быть может SaveFileDialog?

Comment: `textBox1.Text = "";` лишняя строчка, можно убрать.

Comment: эм приложение переписывает все содержимое с открытого файла, в коде же все ясно

Comment: `ReadAllText` ничего не переписывает, он читает.

Comment: весь текст переходит в текст бокс, да и вообще вопрос не про запись данных куда то, а про то как построчно его читать с объекта формы

Answer (score 1):

Используйте StringReader

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader(textbox1.Text)
```

Затем пробегайте циклом все строки

```
string line;
while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    //Ваш код. Текущая строка будет хранится в переменной line
}
```

Когда строки закончатся, метод `ReadLine()` выдаст `null`, и цикл остановится.